# Electron how to add only few modules?

Tags: regex, node.js, electron

I'm trying to build my Electron app with Electron-packager. The problem is my Electron app using **node-notifier** module. When the packaging, I'm using this command:

```
electron-packager . MahApp --ignore='node_modules|.sass-cache|src' --platform=darwin --arch=x64
```

but the problem is that command ignores all node modules. So I edited like this:

```
electron-packager . MahApp --ignore='node_modules\/(?!node-notifier).+|.sass-cache|src' --platform=darwin --arch=x64
```

It seems working because only **'node_modules/node-notifier'** is inside of resources/app. But it won't work because **node-notifier** module itself has extra node modules under the **node_modules** directory like this:

```
./MahApp/node_modules/node-notifier/node_modules/...
```

So it didn't work because any dependencies are not exists. My regex in --ignore_path also ignored inside of node_modules in node_notifier. I don't know what should I do now. I tried to specify the relative path like this:

```
--ignore='./node_modules\/(?!node-notifier).+|...'
```

but it wasn't work.

Comment: I tried this: **--ignore='^node_modules\\/(?!node-notifier).{0,}|\\.sass-cache|src'** but didn't work. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you actually need the node-notifier module? If not, you can `npm uninstall node-notifier --save`, or alternatively, put it only in dev-dependencies and run it with `--prune` option

Comment: Yes I need it. My electron app using it for notifying. It will error on execute without this.

Comment: Well then why do you want to ignore it? @modernator

Comment: I don't want to ignore it. I just want exclude **node-notifier** module only from other modules that will be ignored on packaging. That's why I said "How to **add only few modules**" in the title.

Comment: So what modules exactly are you trying to ignore?

Comment: Also, you can actually use html5 notification api with electron, you dont need extra modules, unless of course its a cli app? See [here](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/desktop-environment-integration/) for more info

Comment: everything excepts **node-notifier**

Comment: Well, then you could move all of your other deps to devdeps, and then run it with --prune option?

Comment: that could be work, but I don't want to do that everytime I build it. I want practical solution.

Comment: @modernator if you move your deps to dev deps in your package.json then you won't have to do any regex. also you could add a build script to your package.json to do it.

Comment: well, every module I installed is devDeps already, but on packaging, they are all in.

Comment: Could you just remove your other modules if you don't want them? I fail to see (may just be me being tired) why you would have them if you don't want to use them? @modernator

Comment: those modules are using for client-side scripts, so I can't remove them. I just want to know why my regex doesn't work(on --ignore) and how to fix it.

Comment: It may be that your first forward slash isn't escaped? @modernator

Comment: nah, I tried. not worked :( anyway, thank you gave me some advice.

Comment: What exactly does it do? Also, try escaping the . at the start? @modernator